# How to see default Java class implementations in IntelliJ-IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sometimes I read the online javadocs and still wonder how a particular method works. *For example,* I was recently looking at the ArrayList online javadoc for Java-11, and I couldn't tell if the "remove" methods shorten the length of the array, or just leave a null value where there used to be an element.

*How can I look at the code implementations of default Java classes in IntelliJ-IDEA?*

Comment: You can download the java11 source code and open it as a project in your ide

Comment: @ZhaoGang I didn't know that, thank you. That's not as easy to do as I would like, but I will look into it.

Comment: Let me be sure I understand your requirement - when you click to follow the code, do you not see any comments or documentation, or do you not know how to click through to see the implementation in the first place?

Comment: @Makoto The second thing you said, I didn't know how to click to see the implementation, or that there necessarily was such a thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "Command + click" on macOS, or "Ctrl + click" on Windows or Linux while the cursor is over the method to see it's implementation. You can also type "command/ctrl + B" instead of clicking, if your caret is inside the method name. If it is ambiguous, IntelliJ will let you choose from a list.

For example, to see the declaration of `remove`, you can write this code:

```
new ArrayList<String>().remove(1)
```

And then command + click to see its declaration:

```
/**
 * Removes the element at the specified position in this list.
 * Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their
 * indices).
 *
 * @param index the index of the element to be removed
 * @return the element that was removed from the list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData(index);

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

Alternatively, you can right click and select "Go to -> Declaration":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

⌘+B is the shortcut to see the full source code of any Java selected class if you are using Mac.